# How to find Unreal GameMode in Unreal Editor content browser?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

Can't find GameMode in Unreal Editor.

Only AActorComponent s are in C++ Classes directory.

Am I missing something?

[Screenshot of Unreal Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbuoF.jpg)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs on https://gamedev.stackexchange.com

Comment: you can close now!

Answer (score 2):

**Must have generated a Blueprints project in the start as opposed to a C++ one by mistake.**

***Why the Issue?***

Blue print project does not provide GameMode class.

Even in C++ project the GameMode class is nothing but empty. But it gives us a class though, blueprint based unreal project don't have one at all(not by default).

I just generated an new C++ project now and added all classes from previous project to the new one!

Answer (score 2):

If you look at Project settings, Maps and Modes you will see the GameMode there, If you havent set one up then it will be pointing to the Default Engine Version,

So then you can create a new Gamemode blueprint/Class based on the engine version of Gamemode then you can repoint the Maps and Modes to your own version